(SDK issues) com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.9.0
I use react-native 0.69.7 and I got this email:

com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.9.0:
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security.
As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

I tried following the doc but it doesn't work. Is there any solution for react-native?

which version of react-native you are using?

Please post your package.json file

i'm using react-native 0.69.7

@gtxtreme you can check it: https://files.fm/f/djusfp9a78

Questions here must be self-contained. Please [edit] your package.json directly into the question. Off-site links frequently break, which makes them much less useful to others in the future.

In our case, com.google.android.play:core was a transitive dependency. This means it was included indirectly through another library. To resolve this, we needed to identify which dependency was using it and update that dependency to the latest version.
Steps to Identify the Dependency Using com.google.android.play:core:

Navigate to the Android Folder:

Open a terminal and navigate to the android directory of your React Native project:
cd android




Run the Gradle Dependencies Command:

Execute the following command to generate a list of all dependencies and their transitive dependencies:
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt




Search for com.google.android.play:core:

Open the dependencies.txt file and search for com.google.android.play:core to find which library is including it.



Example:
In our project, we found that the library sp-react-native-in-app-updates was using com.google.android.play:core as a transitive dependency:
\--- project :sp-react-native-in-app-updates
     +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.68.2 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1

After identifying the dependency, we updated sp-react-native-in-app-updates to its latest version to ensure it uses the latest version of com.google.android.play:core.

What a detailed answer! I got to know today that gradlew has a command to check dependencies as well. Thanks!

you save my day, i'm using react-native-in-app-review and it use com.google.android.play:core and com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
I also checked the release of the library and it is true that they fixed it in the latest version, so just upgrade the library. Thanks

The Play Core Java and Kotlin Library has been partitioned into multiple per-feature Android libraries. use feature libs as per your requirement

@Tian Hey Tian , what do i upgrade exactly ? the react-native-in-app-review to 4.3.3 , or do i upgrade the com.google.android.play:core ?

@android gururu just upgrade react-native-in-app-review to 4.3.3

For our app the dependency was "expo-store-review" at 5.1.1 - hoping this will be possible to upgrade on our legacy codebase.
Many thanks for the detailed answer, extremely helpful and appreciated.

@Manju JK, out of curiosity - after you updated, what new version replaced 1.9.1?

@JCraine Actually, we are overriding it to ourself in our build.gradle. We are currently using 2.1.0 version.

@android gururu sr, about react-native-in-app-review you need upgrade and create patch file follow this issue
react-native-in-app-review/issues/175

The issue should be at build.gradle app level, probably you miss the migration to Play Core:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore?hl=it#groovy
For example I had the same issue with an Android Native application, I had the play dependencies like the following:
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

Which I replace with:
implementation 'com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.2.0'


They split core into 4 asset-delivery, feature-delivery, review, app-update.  I removed core and noted what broke when I tried to compile.  All I needed was review.

For Cordova users:
I had to update cordova-launch-review plugin to version 4.1.0. It uses the maven dependency com.google.android.play:review instead of the deprecated com.google.android.play:core one.

If your app uses com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3, it includes com.google.android.play:core version 1.9.1 as a transitive dependency.
To fix this, update aws-storage-s3 to version 2.1.0 or higher, which requires a  minSdk level of 24.
For Kotlin 1.5.31, use version 1.37.10. Please find the updated details here.
For other dependencies, refer to this StackOverflow answer.
